# get attribute value by its name

Tags: c++, sax, xerces

In my c++ code and in using xerces for sax parsing , i want to have attribute's value
by it's name .
how can i do that ?
there is some thing like this in xerces document , but doesn't work :

```
String identifier = atts.getValue("id");
```

thanks in advance

Comment: this code generates a compile error like this : can't convert char* to xml_sizet

Comment: Use [`transcode`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXMLString.html#91b02742b80418fbc6c54b7dd353ad8c) on the return of `getValue` and assign to a const char*

Comment: char* from = XMLString::transcode(attrs.getValue("from"));  it generates this error : invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘XMLSize_t {aka long unsigned int}’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem using

```
XMLCh* identity= XMLString::transcode("id");
char* identityVal = XMLString::transcode(attrs.getValue(identity));
```